# schema does not exist error in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, schema, postgresql-9.1

i have below tables and functions while executing the below function in postgresql ,it is showing ERROR:  schema "tblmark" does not exist.Please help.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks"("DPID" TEXT,"From" TEXT,"Name" TEXT);

INSERT INTO "LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks" VALUES ('1','ram','kumar');

CREATE TABLE "LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation"("DPID" TEXT,"Pntref" TEXT)

INSERT INTO "LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation" VALUES ('1','ram');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetParcelNonParcel(PlanID TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $GetParcelNonParcel$
DECLARE
    tblMark RECORD;
    parCount INTEGER;
    parNonCount INTEGER;
    totalParNonCount TEXT;
    tblCou INTEGER;
BEGIN
    parCount=0;
    parNonCount=0;

    FOR tblMark IN (SELECT * FROM "LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks" WHERE "DPID" = PlanID) LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tblCou FROM "LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation"
            WHERE "DPID"=PlanID
                AND (
                    "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark.From || ',' || tblMark.Name '%'
                    OR
                    "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark.Name || ',' || tblMark.From '%'
                );

        RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', tblCou;

        IF tblCou > 0 THEN
            parCount = parCount + 1;
            RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', parCount;
        ELSE
            parNonCount = parNonCount + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    totalParNonCount = CAST(parCount AS TEXT) || ',' || CAST(parNonCount AS TEXT);
    RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', totalParNonCount;
    RETURN totalParNonCount;
END;
$GetParcelNonParcel$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select GetParcelNonParcel('1');
```

While executing above function,it is showing ERROR:  schema "tblmark" does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SELECT` inside the `FOR` loop, you have the following condition:

```sql
... AND (
        "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark.From || ',' || tblMark.Name '%'
        OR
        "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark.Name || ',' || tblMark.From '%'
        )
```

You are missing the concatenation-operator `||` for the trailing `'%'` both times. Also, you are not properly referencing the columns of your record. Since you established them with `"` (double-quotes), you will always need to refer to them exactly the same way (This is a reason why you should not do this. So if it is not to late, change it to names without quotes.).

Using your momentary columnnames, this should help you:

```sql
... AND (
        "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark."From" || ',' || tblMark."Name" || '%'
        OR
        "Pntref" LIKE '%' || tblMark."Name" || ',' || tblMark."From" || '%'
        )
```